# When are option hashes (at the end) not allowed in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, syntax-error, railstutorial.org

In Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition (6.2 user validations)
While writing some test, the book has this code for the ActiveRecord User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: case_sensitive: false
end
```

The last line ( uniqueness: case_sensitive: false ) throws a syntax error.

The online version for this is corrected to have {} :
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users to

```
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

But my question is *why* does the last line throw an error? I thought the last hash could always omit the {}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It throws an error because the following statement is not a valid Ruby statement:

```
uniqueness: case_sensitive: false
```

It should be

```
{ uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }}
```

When passing a Hash to a method, you can omit the `{}`.

```
call_method(foo: "bar")
call_method({ foo: "bar" })
```

But in your case it's completely different: you are defining a hash containing keys such as `presence`, `format`, `uniqueness`. The value of the key `uniqueness` is supposed to be a `Hash` as well, but you are not defining it properly.

```
call_method(foo: { bar: "baz" }) # valid
call_method({ foo: { bar: "baz" }}) # valid
call_method(foo: bar: baz) # invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only omit "one level" of hash braces.

So in this right here:

```
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

the second argument to the `validates` method is actually a hash. You can visualize it like so:

```
  validates(:email, { presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 } })
```

If you have a nested hash structure (like you do here) and you're already omitting the braces for the top-level hash, then you can't omit them for the nested one.

In Coffeescript, though, you can do this (which I find neat)